# How to scheduler HDFS Balancer in Cloudera Manager?

Tags: hdfs, schedule, cloudera-manager

Anyone have the idea on how to schedule hdfs-balancer in Cloudera Manager, and to have it run on a scheduled basis - probably every Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hdfs balance command, and make it in the cron on one of your nodes:

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs balancer -threshold 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I have scheduled this in my hdfs user's cron and it works fine

## rebalancing HDFS weekly job

00 10 * * SAT hdfs balancer -threshold 5 >> /app/hadoop_users/sf/rebal_log.txt